# Data transfer to a mesh with different topology

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, modifiers, vertex-weights

Is it possible to transfer mesh data such as UV map projection and vertex weights to another mesh that has different topology?

I thought the Data Transfer Modifier could do this, but I haven't figured out how to make it work. Or maybe I am mistaken?

I made a test .blend of a very simple scene containing three spheres, each with different topology. The Roundcube is textured and weighted, but the other two are not. **How can I make the other two spheres use the texture space and approximated weights of the Roundcube?**

[image: Three spheres created for testing the Data Transfer Modifier]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should use the data transfer **operator** instead (easier to repeat for try/retry and... I never succeeded to use the modifier...). To use it: place object so that they overlap, select the destination(s), then select active the source. Use ctrl+shift+T. But, considering the topology here: UV map won't give a good result; Vertex weights may be good

Comment: @lemon Hey, thanks! I tried transferring the UV data and it generated a new UV map on the Icosphere that was very similar to the original in its result! It had imperfections at the seams, but definitely usable. Could probably clone-paint those areas and save a new texture image that would work on it. As for transferring vertex groups/weights it only transferred one group - do you know how to get it to transfer all of them?

Comment: For the vertex groups, choose "all layers" as source layer instead of "active layer"

Comment: @lemon I see all the options now. My Operator Panel was hidden before. Thanks! This worked really well in my test. This is really useful info. It's still bugging me that I don't know why the Data Transfer Modifier doesn't work, but this method is just as good of a solution in most cases, I think.

Comment: About the modifier I really don't know... but considering the modifier needs to be applied... the operator does the job too and it is much more simple to use in my opinion

Comment: @lemon I agree. If you'd like to post your advice as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Mentalist, I could do. But as I am surely missing something about the modifier (always failed to make it work as I want), I prefer these 'advice like' comments than a real answer. But fell free to write one if you want.

Comment: @lemon I understand. In any case, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get a uv transfer using the the *Data Transfer Modifier*.

Select object to transfer the UVs to, add the *Data Transfer Modifier*

In the source parameter select the model to get the uvs from, check on *Face Corner Data*.

In *Face Corner Data* check on *UVs*. In the mapping parameter select *Nearest Face Interpolated*.

Also, clicking off the *Object Transform* button next to the *Source* parameter is great if your source object has been moved away from your destination object.